# Stripe Payment - Do Not Redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I have my stripe payment up and working. However I am wanting the user to be able to make the payment without leaving the page they are on.

Is it possible to submit a Stripe Payment using Node without redirecting?

Thanks so much! Here is my code:

```
 app.post('/quizPayment', function(req, res) {   
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_key");

// Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
// Charge the user's card:
stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: "usd",
  description: "JobQuiz",
  source: token,
}, function(err, charge) {
  // asynchronously called
});
//I dont want to redirect here
});
```

Comment: Sure, just return an OK back to the client... how is this method being called? AJAX or an actual form POST?

Comment: Thanks for the info! Currently its in a form POST

Comment: So by default, a form POST will refresh the page - rather than doing that, use an AJAX call and hit your method, no refresh will happen then.

Comment: What's around this block of code?  Is there an event attached to creating the charge?